# I have owerwriten my style.css in Atom and then it crashed so it's blank now, but I have opened webpage in browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, opera, atom-editor

Please, if anybody knows how to solve this disaster.

I have erased my style.css content in Atom editor and then the editor crashed. Now, the file is blank.

However, I have opened the webiste in several Firefox tabs as well as in Chrome and Opera.

Please, can you help me to find a way how to get the style.css file back.

There should be a way how to get it if it's in browser opened.

Comment: Time to start using source control...

Comment: Right click the page > view page source > look for a link to `style.css` > open it and save

Comment: If I click on view page source's link to the css file, it's empty. The page is blank ;(

Comment: Is it possible to do a memory dump of Firefox webpage.

Comment: In firefox go to inspect element and click on any markup like div.. right hand side it will show css.. just click on style.css above right corner it will open editor within firefox.. now save it either by copying all or using ctrl+shift+s to do save as

Comment: @MJN it will open a blank file ;(

Comment: styling is still present in opened tabs or just markup?

Comment: @MJN I have solved it ;D. Check my answer.

Comment: @zmachanic I have solved it. Check my answer for how to get the orignial/loaded style.css content.

Comment: thats what i was pointing out..

Comment: @MJN no, your solution with right hand side opens file you have to set it and select in the left part of Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this guys ;D !!!

So, if anybody needs to solve this in the future, the key is to select "Live Edit" instead of "Source Edit" and select the css file from the select box on the left and then copy the stuff that will show up. Source edit will show nothing aka blank page content.

Here is what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the CSS from Google Web Cache - [check this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en). Maybe Google saved the page you were working on, IF it was publicly available.

Comment: It' on localhost ;(